# Difference between Pantone FORMULA GUIDE and DESIGNER FIELD GUIDE?

Tags: pantone

I need to buy a new Pantone color swatch. I need one that says which percentage of Pantone colors are needed to create another Pantone colors (read: formula guide).

Now, I read that newer color swatches pages are very thin, I'd like to have heavy cardboard pages, like in old guides.

Maybe the DESIGNER FIELD guide has heavier pages? I don't really understand the difference between the two guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, the only real difference in Pantone's "Field Guide" is the tear out chips. If you need chips to attach with client proofs or whatever and you don't want to buy a separate chip book, go with the Field Guide.

Personally, I never use chips any more. I just stick with the standard fan books. If for some reason I need a sample of the ink, I ask the printer for a draw down on the actual paper and use that in client discussions.

Comment: Yes I don't use chips either - they are too troublesome when the printer is not 100% accurate in some troublesome colors like greens and oranges :-P

Comment: A Pantone salesman confirmed this (the only difference is the tear out chips) when I ordered the Formula Guide

Answer (score 2):

in terms of content there is no difference, it is the combination between chips and a guide. You can remove a chip or handle the guide as always